# Apache - RewriteCond - I want the Pattern to use Environment Variables but won't work - Alternatives?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want the Pattern to use an Environment Variable I have previously created via the flags options on the RewriteRule but this is not allowed.

What I am looking for are for alternatives?

> Problem:
>  I want to redirect (via Proxy) to a different Tomcat instance
>   (on a different port) but based on which Client Certificate is chosen
>   - i.e. the Client Subject DN, which I have got.

I want to go from this:-
`RewriteCond %{SSL:SSL_CLIENT_S_DN} "CN=User (POP00001|POP222222)" [NC]`

to be able to read from a file (I thought of MapRewrite but that is for the rewrite not the condition pattern) a list of valid users

Any ideas please?

thanks

EDIT:
I am using Apache 2.2.14 so can't use the "expr" and BNF :(

Answer (score 0):

What I want to do is not possible. The regex backreferences can't work in my situation. I do wonder if the 2.2.14 expr might have worked??